# Interpreting this template-related compiler message

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm compiling a very old codebase under Visual Studio 2017.  The code compiles, but the compiler is emitting the following messages, which I don't know how to interpret.

**EDIT:  Here's the unaltered compiler output**

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Obsidian.DSP.DirectShow, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>clock.cpp
1>parsing with MACROS
1>s:\library\obsidian.dsp.directshow\mpeg2demux\mp2demux\clock.cpp(962): warning C4101: 'rtDelta': unreferenced local variable
1>s:\library\obsidian.dsp.directshow\mpeg2demux\mp2demux\clock.cpp(1277): warning C4101: 'rtGetTime': unreferenced local variable
1>s:\library\obsidian.dsp.directshow\mpeg2demux\mp2demux\clock.cpp(286): warning C4101: 'pHead': unreferenced local variable
1>s:\library\obsidian.dsp.directshow\mpeg2demux\mp2demux\clock.cpp(282): note: while compiling class template member function 'void CTClockSubordinate<LONGLONG,LONGLONG>::OnMasterTime(MasterClock)'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            MasterClock=LONGLONG
1>        ]
1>s:\library\obsidian.dsp.directshow\mpeg2demux\mp2demux\clock.cpp(1566): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void CTClockSubordinate<LONGLONG,LONGLONG>::OnMasterTime(MasterClock)' being compiled
1>        with
1>        [
1>            MasterClock=LONGLONG
1>        ]
1>s:\library\obsidian.dsp.directshow\mpeg2demux\mp2demux\clock.h(410): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'CTClockSubordinate<LONGLONG,LONGLONG>' being compiled
1>AssemblyInfo.obj : /DEBUG:FASTLINK is not supported when managed code is present; restarting link with /DEBUG:FULL
1>AssemblyInfo.obj : MSIL module encountered; incremental linking is disabled for MSIL; performing full link
1>Obsidian.DSP.DirectShow.vcxproj -> S:\Obsidian.Topaz\x64\Debug\Obsidian.DSP.DirectShow.dll
1>ALINK : warning AL1073: Referenced assembly 'mscorlib.dll' targets a different processor
1>Done building project "Obsidian.DSP.DirectShow.vcxproj".
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 16 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

That's it, no more information. Is it some kind of warning?  Should I modify the code?

Here's an example of how one of these templates are defined (under a .cpp file)

```
template <class HostClock,class MasterClock>
void
CTClockSubordinate <HostClock, MasterClock>::OnMasterTime (
    IN  MasterClock   MasterTime
    )
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Strange that there is no warning code. Is this really a full compiler log?

Comment: Oh, I think I get it - the note is part of the warning for line 286?

Comment: yes, normally..

Comment: You code contains unused local variables. Just comment or delete them.

Comment: @Jarod42, thanks I thought it was an independent message and made little sense to me.  Feel free to post an answer and will gladly accept it.